# Is there a way to enable checkboxes in the Nemo file manager?

Tags: files, directory, filemanager, nemo

Is there a way to enable checkboxes in the Nemo file manager to select multiple files/folders?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

Open Nemo

```
$ nemo
```

You could choose the multiple file and folders by keeping press the **CTRL** key and choosing the multiple files with the mouse pointer left-click button.

Press **CTRL** + **mouse left-click**

[image]